# Segmentation fault error with pointer array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I am trying to test some code from "Pointers On C", the find_char function, which searches for a specified character. I added something of my own, that is, the main() function that calls the find_char and includes the initialized data to be searched(an array of pointers to char). I managed to fix all errors and warnings at compile time, but while trying to run the a.out file, I got the segmentation fault error.

I know segmentation fault is mostly concerned with array and pointers which so often happens when types are incorrectly translated. But I really can't find what is wrong with my code.

Thank you so much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0

int find_char( char **strings, char value);

int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char c = 'z';
    char *pps[] = { 
            "hello there",
            "good morning",
            "how are you"
    };  
    i = find_char(pps, c); 
    printf("%d\n", i); 
    return 0;
}

int find_char (char **strings, char value)
{
    char *string;
    while (( string = *strings++) != NULL)
    {   
            while (*string != '\0')
            {   
                    if( *string++ == value )
                            return TRUE;
            }   
    }   
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: If you're going to test for a null string pointer in your array of string pointers,  perhaps you should actually *put one at the end of the list*. I.e. `"how are you", NULL`. Right now your code hits the last string (which is obviously non-null), then just continues marching into the ether in search of exactly what you asked it to: a NULL.

Comment: Or pass the number of strings as a parameter to `find_char`, e.g. `int find_char( char **strings, size_t n, char value);` and iterate with a `for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)` loop or `while (n--)` to only iterate over the proper number of pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well your problem come from your outer while loop. It loops over the strings in the array until it finds a `NULL` string. However, you didn't terminate the array with such string, so the loop will go on after the 3rd string and end up trying to access memory it isn't supposed to.

**A solution to your problem:**
You can modify your function's signature by giving it a `size` parameter so that it becomes

```
int find_char(const **char strs, int size, char ch);
```

Then you need to include this size value in the looping process to find your stop condition.

```
char *s = NULL;
int i = 0;
while (i++ < size && (s = *strs++)) {
    // ...
}
```

The point to remember here is that, in C programming it is required to play with memory and arrays carefully. When dealing with arrays, one usually want to pass the array's size as a parameter to each processing functions.

I hope that helped.

Comment: Or simply `while (size-- && (s = *strs++))`, or eliminate `s` and just use indexing, e.g. `for (int i = 0; i < size && strs[i]; i++)`. All are fine as is your answer.

Comment: Yes there are many ways of doing it. C is very permissive on that regard. Thanks for completing my answer.